# Not loading shared libraries error when trying to run ghc after installing Haskell Platform

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

I just installed Haskell platform core from the tar ball on my Antergos install and when i try to run ghc i get an error

```
`/usr/local/haskell/ghc-8.4.3-x86_64/lib/ghc-8.4.3/bin/ghc: error while loading shared libraries: libtinfo.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`
```

not sure if this is something i can resolve or something that is an issue with haskell platform.

Comment: this seems to be a similar issue (there are hints at how to fix it in the link): https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1012 ... but maybe you already read this, because I just googled the error message :)

Answer (score 0):

The ghc distributed with the platform links against libtinfo.so.5 and apparently your system doesn't have it. Depending on the details of your distro, you might be able to install the compat package for this, or use the advice in https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/446927-missing-library-libtinfo-so-5 or https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/778